# Composite C1: How to retrieve data from datatypes?

Tags: c#, c1-cms

I'm attempting to create more dynamic slider so I've created a custom datatype which one includes fields like `Caption, Text, Link, Image, StartDate, EndDate, Active,` etc... I hope I'm in the right path.

Now I need to retrieve active entries. How can I get the necessary entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query data using LINQ through the Get method on the [`Composite.Data.DataConnection`](http://api.composite.net/html/T_Composite_Data_DataConnection.htm) class - `dataConnection.Get<T>()` where T is your data type wield an IQueryable.

Below is code that will query a data type named Your.Data.Type, filtering on the Caption field and selecting Caption, Text, Image and StartDate.

```
using  (DataConnection connection = new DataConnection())
{
   var myData = 
      from d in connection.Get<Your.Data.Type>()
      where  d.Caption == "My Caption"
      select new { d.Caption, d.Text, d.Image, d.StartDate };
}
```

On the Composite C1 documentation website you can read more [about accessing data with C#](http://docs.composite.net/Data/AccessingDataWithCSharp/How-to-Query-Data-Using-LINQ).

If you are not into C# you can use either [Visual Functions](http://users.composite.net/Functions/A-Guide-to-Visual-Functions) or [XSLT Functions](http://docs.composite.net/XSLT).

Comment: I've created a C# function and generated the html code like this: http://pastebin.com/2p3y17si  which looks ugly, but it works.

Comment: How can I embed C# function's result into XSLT function? I tried this and it displayed as html code (encoded) on the page: http://pastebin.com/XZegvApb

Comment: You can always call C# Functions (any function returning string of XElement results) from the XSLT's Function Calls tab. You can also call them dynamically, see http://docs.composite.net/XSLT/Calling-C1-Functions

Comment: There is only one slider data I got. How can I clone datatype to use multiple instances of the slider? Adding a slider id field is the easiest way but I wonder how can I add separate data for Slide1 Slide2 etc...